# Send Data from iPhone to Server

Tags: ios, asp.net, swift, post

I was trying to send data from iphone (iOS 8 - Swift) to Server (asp.net).
In the moment i can GET information from asp.net, but I can't POST data from my iPhone.

This is my function **POST** in Swift

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.0.79/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/InsertEmployee/");

    //let myUrl2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: str)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    // Compose a query string
    let postString = "name=James&lastname=Bond";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")

            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        println("response = \(response)")

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:

        var err: NSError?
        var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = myJSON {
            // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
            var firstNameValue = parseJSON["firstName"] as? String
            println("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
        }

    }

    task.resume()
```

My code in asp.net is:

```
   public interface IPostEmployees
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/InsertEmployee/{id1}/{id2}")]
    bool InsertEmployeeMethod(string id1, string id2);
}
```

And

```
  public bool InsertEmployeeMethod(string id1, string id2)
   {

       int success = 0;
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=SQLREPORTES;database=prueba;persist security info=True;user id=MYUSER;password=MYPASSWORD;multipleactiveresultsets=True;"))
       {
           conn.Open();

           //decimal value = Decimal.Parse(id3);
           string cmdStr = string.Format("INSERT INTO dbo.EmpDB VALUES('{0}','{1}')", id1, id2);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
           success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           conn.Close();
       }

       return (success != 0 ? true : false);
   }
```

I want send a NAME and a LASTNAME, 2 parameters, but show a error:
**status code: 404**
**END NOT FOUND**

¿What thing i was doing wrong? thanks

PD: Based on this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405189/How-to-access-SQL-database-from-an-iPhone-app-Via

Comment: It is usually a good practice to test server API via Web browser (e.g. Google Chrome's Postman extension) first. And then, implement the communication on the client side (e.g. iPhone).

Comment: could you check if API is hit by your application? by using log / running app in local server/developpers' computer in debug mode...

Comment: I was looking and, my file web.config is wrong... but i don`t know what I have to do. And thanks for the help (postman is a great app, i disn't know it)